# Date-time stamp conversion in javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime, extjs4.1

I have Date String `Thu May 23 2013 18:19:32 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` from my database. I want to make in this format `THURSDAY May 23 2013 18:19:32 GMT 0500 CDT` in ext-js.any idea ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have code that you have tried?

Comment: Your question is too vague, however you need to use the parse/format strings, all the info you need is here: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.Date

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 excellent ate parsing libraries available tat you can use. They are both very small

- https://code.google.com/p/datejs/
- http://momentjs.com/

Sample datejs usage:

```
Date.parse('Thu, 1 July 2004 22:30:00 GMT') // Thu Jul 01 2004 16:30:00
```

You can then format the date object in whatever format you require for output.

Comment: Ahh, ok, I missed that in the question.